# What window is playing audio?

Tags: mac, audio

I've got a number of windows open, including several browser windows.  One of them is playing an annoying advertising video.

How can I easily locate which window is playing audio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ability to see per-application sound output: Check out https://superuser.com/questions/150304/per-application-volume-settings-possible-on-mac-os-x-snow-leopard

Within Chrome, you can use the [Mutetab](http://www.mutetab.com/) extension to see what tabs/windows are playing audio.

Comment: Everybody can edit answers anyway, there is no need to turn it into a community wiki for that.

Comment: This doesn't help.  The OP asked how to find out which app is playing sound; this question asked how to control sound level of individual apps which is a completely different issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could use chrome developer tools to inspect the page you are viewing. Click on the resources tab to inspect what resources are used.

Answer (score 0):

1.) Close one window after the other and locate the sound. Then reload using the history tab.
2.) Install AdBlock and you don't need to care about it anymore!

Comment: I think 1.) is not what the OP meant by easily ;)